# sencha app build production is generating 910 JS files in plain text

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-cmd

Im trying to build my application using **sencha app build production**, and it takes a long time to load, then when I open the index page, I see there are reference to 910 JS files, all of them in plain text.

I have read that if I mention my files in a requires:[] config they will be combined in a production build, but in this case I am seeing the whole WS library being loaded.

I am running an app that I created from one of the Ext templates this way:
**sencha generate app -s templates/admin-dashboard/ AMS ../AMS**

Can someone please point me in the right direction where I should look?

Here a an screeenshot of a piece of the JS imports generated:
[image]

Comment: Maybe the sencha documentation?

Comment: Sencha docs says to run sencha app build production, this is an out of the box application generated by a sencha comand line, it should build in prod mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are loading `index.html` from the root of the project (`.../AMS`) which will not point to your production build. When you do `sencha app build` it will build the app and everything would then be in `build/production/AMS/`. If you want to load that build in the browser, you should load the `index.html` from that directory, not the `index.html` in the root of the project. The `index.html` in the root of your project will always be for development.

The same is true for a testing build (`sencha app build testing`) only in the `build/testing/AMD/`.

Comment: I'm guessing this is in the sencha documentation.

Comment: Thanks Mitchell. Perfect answer, very helpful.